# Kendo Grid - Dynamic Column and Custom Template

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, dynamic-columns, kendo-template

I have a problem with kendo Grid and Custom template. The problem is, I need to check the value of the column

- if Value == 1, I need to change it to Icon Check
- If Value == 0, I need to change it to Icon Delete
- If Value == -1. I need to return empty html

This is the Example Code : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hG6zR/16/)

```
var myFields = {
        no: { },
        section: { },
        service: { }
    };
for(var x = 0 ; x < dataList.length; x++){
    myFields["data"+x] = { };
}

    var no = 0;
var myColumns = [
                 { title: "No", locked: true, width: 50, template: function(e){return ++no; } },
                 { field: "section", title: "Hole Section", locked: true, width: 130 },
                 { field: "service", title: "Services", locked: true, width: 200 }
                 /* other columns ... */
             ];
for(var x = 0 ; x < dataList.length; x++){
    myColumns.push( { field: "data"+x, title: dataList[x], width: 100, locked: false});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/hG6zR/17/)**

**Solution**: You can change your data fed into the grid by **replacing the numbers with a icon**. I prefer using **[FontAwesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)** as it is very light weight.

CDN for font awesome.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css

Code change to make changes into your data is as below.

```
tableData[tableData.length - 1]["data"+c] = formatCellData(dataOffset[c].selected); 
// replace you code with function call.
```

the function definition is as below.

```
function formatCellData(value){
  switch(value){
  case 1:  return "<i class='fa fa-check''></i>";break;
  case 0:  return "<i class='fa fa-trash''></i>";break;
  case -1: return "";break;
  default: return "";
  }
}
```

Now this will make sure you get the HTML part instead of the numbers,

Now we need to make sure the HTML string is read as a regular HTML and icons are displayed and not the HTML string as is, So add this `encoded: false` attribute into your column data.

```
for(var x = 0 ; x < dataList.length; x++){
 myColumns.push( { field: "data"+x, title: dataList[x], width: 100, locked: false,encoded: false});
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DavidVincent Glad to help :)